# Beneftis of Hybrid Data Structures on Efficiency

Tags: algorithm, inheritance, data-structures, tree, linked-list

I have this homework assignment in my Computer Science class that involves combining different data structures for apparent increased efficiency

TL;DR --- Scroll Down

""""Build a data structure which behaves like a linked list with a binary tree as an indexing structure. It should be able to be used as a linked list and inherited from to construct indexed queues and indexed stacks. You may assume that all things that will be put into this data structure are Comparable, so that the indexing tree will function as a binary search tree. You should build a class of iterators to facilitate interaction with this data structure. Insertion into the list can be done 'after' a location specified by a list iterator (which could sometimes be returned by a find method). Naturally, in an inherited indexed queue, insertion will only be at the back of the queue, however the indexing via the tree will need to preserve the binary search tree ordering, and similarly for an inherited indexed stack. You should have methods to insert and delete, and methods to find (returning an iterator) and sort (any sorting technique will suffice for this question, though you might well want to take advantage of the inherent ordering information derived from the tree!!). Test this structure using a main method which plays with people (perhaps compared via height?).""""

TL;DR --- What are the benefits of having Binary Search Tree nodes containing the same Objects as doubly linked list nodes?

Also, how would inheritance work with such a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the benefits of having Binary Search Tree nodes containing the same Objects as doubly linked list nodes?

Perhaps a better way of asking the same question would be "what are the benefits of connecting the nodes of a Binary Search Tree (BST) with additional links to construct a linked list out of the same nodes?"

The benefit of adding an extra link is an ability to iterate over the entire tree using `O(1)` memory. Without this additional link you would need `O(Log(N))` memory to iterate the tree, because you would need to keep the position at each level.

The "payment" for this is the use of additional `O(N)` blocks of memory for the links, and a somewhat more complex algorithm for maintaining the data structure. This may be a fair deal when you iterate the same tree a significant number of times, while insertions and modifications are generally rare.

> How would inheritance work with such a list?

Rather than inheriting from a list and also from a tree, you would implement interfaces for the list and for the tree.

Comment: For clarification, you are saying that by generating a list from the tree that is sorted, on can iterate over that list more efficiently than iterating over the tree directly?

Comment: @jeanluc No, you are not generating a list, you are maintaining both a list and a tree at the same time. Your `ListTreeNode` class has three `ListTreeNode` links - `next`, `left`, and `right`. When you insert or delete an item, you maintain both of these links (if a list is doubly-linked, there may also be a forth item `previous`). The presence of the `next` / `previous` links helps you iterate over the "list-tree" hybrid without using an explicit or an implicit stack.